# how to get campaigns and ad using Marketing API

Tags: facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

i am having trouble getting campaigns and ads using Marketing API.
can someone help me in getting it with details.
it just shows a blank array.

Comment: Share your code so we can assist you better

Comment: is this url ok [https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/1730116840574739?method=GET&path=6054370474531%2Fads&version=v2.7]

Answer (score 0):

You can at first get AdAccounts:

> /me/adaccounts

and then

> /<act_123>/campaigns

Comment: thnx it just shows the id of the campaign.but i want details of it and how to get ads and its details using the campaign id.

Comment: append `&metadata=1` https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api

Comment: thats good it shows the meta data.
but i think u didnt catch me. wat i am actually asking for  is ?
i am actually asking for the data not the meta data.

Comment: Metadata is exactly what you want -- it lists the existing 'edges' of the object. For example, if in `/<campaign_id>?metadata=1` you see `"name"` it means you can call the `/<campaign_id>/name`, etc.

Comment: i tried the following but i got the below exception
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
url  : /<campaign_id>/name
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
exception :
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unknown path components: /name",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 2500,
    "fbtrace_id": "GW46wj8+wY5"
  }
}

Comment: but it shows the metadata by using  

url : /<campaign_id>?metadata=1

Comment: My bad. To retrieve fields (not edge listings) you should use this syntax: `/<campaign_id>?fields=name`

Comment: ok that works good then how to get the ads inside the campaigns

Comment: In the similar way you got campaigns of adaccount. Metadata lists available edges at the bottom of JSON.

Comment: i m sorry i didnt get what you are trying to say.
can plz help me out with an example .?

Comment: You should really reread the comments. They have link to documentation and reusable examples.

Comment: i am sorry to say this. but i am not able to see the link.